# How to $_POST an array from select tag using php?

Tags: php, arrays, select, post

This form contains many other inputs that work fine like `<input>, <select> (not multiple) etc...`I cannot figure out where exactly my problem is when I use `<select multiple`. I have the following code:

```
<form action="phpaction.php" method="post">
<select name="states[]" multiple>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
...
</select>
```

```
// phpaction.php file
$statesArray=$_POST['states'];
print_r ($statesArray);
```

Why is not it working? I get the following error: `Undefined index: states in phpaction.php on line 72`

Comment: Pretty sure it's `print_r($statesArray);`.

Comment: whats the output if you do print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: @Dave Chen I get the error earlier than that...`Undefined index: states in phpaction.php on line 72` So it does not recognize the states[] array

Comment: @Tucker Even if I do not print, I get `Undefined index: states in phpaction.php on line 72`

Comment: If the HTML file and the PHP file are the same file, then you will get that error if you try to access `states` from `$_POST` if the user didn't post anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {
    $statesArray=$_POST['states'];
    print_r($statesArray);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="states[]" multiple>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```